# Custom authentication with Symfony 5.4 - User's credentials are good but not authenticated

Tags: php, authentication, symfony

I updated a Symfony app from 4.4 to 5.4 but the authentication is fully deprecated.

With the new way to authenticate a user, I updated my app but the user still not authenticated.

I'm using a JwtToken class, it extends AbstractToken. I could use setAuthenticated(true) but this one is also deprecated. How can I replace this method?

Here, the authenticate method from the custom authenticator:

```php
public function authenticate(Request $request): Passport
{
        $credentials = $request->request->all();

        try {
            $tokens = $this->userLoginManager->getTokensByCredentials($credentials['email'], $credentials['password']);
        } catch (\Exception $exception) {
            throw new UserNotFoundException($exception->getMessage());
        }

        $this->token = $tokens['token'] ?? null;
        $this->refreshToken = $tokens['refreshToken'] ?? null;

        $authenticatedToken = $this->userLoginManager->createAuthenticatedToken($tokens['token'], $tokens['refreshToken']);
        $this->tokenStorage->setToken($authenticatedToken);

        $userBadge = new UserBadge($tokens['token'], function () use ($authenticatedToken) {
            $user = $this->userManager->me();
            $authenticatedToken->setUser($user);
            //$authenticatedToken->setAuthenticated(true);
            $this->tokenStorage->setToken($authenticatedToken);
            return $user;
        });

        $passport = new Passport($userBadge, new CustomCredentials(
            fn ($credentials, User $user) => $user->getEmail() === $credentials['email'],
            $credentials
        ));

        $passport->setAttribute('authenticated_token', $authenticatedToken);

        return $passport;
}
```

And the createAuthenticatedToken method:

```php
public function createAuthenticatedToken(string $token, string $refreshToken): TokenInterface
{
        return new JwtToken(
            $token,
            $refreshToken,
            $this->tokenDecoder->decode($token, $this->authPubKey)
        );
}
```

Thanks for helping me!